# How to assign a variable in my python script?

Tags: python

im new to python and i have have script that need to parse different urls 
for now i have been able only to make it like this..
i would like to assign a variable into URLList {0 to 10} instead of my solution
thanks you very much

```
def ReadUrl():
    URLList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',]
    extracted_data =[]
    for i in URLList:
        url = "http://www.exemple.com/?&page="+i
        print "Processing: "+url
        extracted_data.append(SiteParser(url))
        sleep(3)
        f = open('urls.json','w')
        json.dump(extracted_data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: "assign a variable into URLList" - huh?

Comment: sorry its the only way i could explain

Answer (score 1):

Use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) (or `range` in Python 3):

```
for i in xrange(1, 11):
    url = "http://www.exemple.com/?&page=" + str(i)
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: thanks you Deep Space , i had try this solution but forgot to add the  "str"                  now it got it working :) i have vote but i have low point (and its seem that i will have 0 point for ever...)